# Does time dilate during night time when earth orbits around the sun?

Tags: observational-astronomy

Number of the solar middays (noon) = Number of the solar midnights (ALWAYS). The diagram (Top view but not to the scale) in the following link depicts the path traced by the earth in its orbit (either circular or elliptical) around the sun.
[image: Earth in its Orbit]
https://i.postimg.cc/C5K2wX6V/IMG-3066.jpg

Both Midnight and Midday happen simultaneously and instantly. Any point on the outer circle represents solar midnight while on the inner circle solar noon. It's quite clear that the length (circumference) of the outer circle is greater than the length (circumference) of the inner circle. This means after the completion of one year, the occurrences of the Midnights are more the occurrences of Middays.

Earth not only rotates around its own axis but also revolves around the sun in its orbit however both axial and orbital motion of earth independent of each other. There is a possibility that the earth may glide w/o rotation for a short while and time dilate but such things never noticed either.

Comment: "This means after the completion of one year, the occurrences of the Midnights are more the occurrences of Middays."  I don't understand the reasoning here.  Do you mean that a location on earth will have more "midnights" than "middays"  ?    Anyway, there is certainly no stop and glide, and reletivistic time dialtion is not relevent.  But I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: @ James K, The diagram shows the top view of the earth when it orbits around the sun in its orbit. Earth is represented by a circle. So for simplicity, consider the occurrences of midnights and middays at the equator or close to the equator of the earth when it orbits around the sun in its orbit.

Comment: I cannot access your diagram; please consider editing your question to include your figure directly.

Comment: I guess an alternative Question would be: is the time dilation different on the earth surface for noon and midnight?

Answer (score 3):

There's no gliding and no significant time dilation.

Your speed relative to the sun is not the same at midnight as it is at midday, since you must combine the rotation of the Earth with its orbital motion around the sun.

But for any point on Earth there will be one midnight and one midday each day. There aren't "more midnights".

Comment: @ James K, For every noon there is anti-noon. Greater orbital velocity of midnight means it glides if every point on the inner circle is noon. If midnight glides then noon also glide but less than midnight due to its lower orbital velocity relative to the sun during the combined motion (orbital and axial) of the earth in its orbit. Midnights are more than the Midday if we join all noon and anti-noon via straight line in the figure. You denied gliding but I don't see any other possibility.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about. The plant rotates and orbits in a nearly circular ellipse.  No gliding. No dilation.  You are seeing a problem where there really is none.

Comment: @ James K - Join every noon on the inner circle to its receptive midnight on the outer circle and extend their lines to the sun. Not every point/anti-noon on the outer circle find its match /noon on the inner circle if noon and midnight happens at once / instantly. The only possibility I can see that midnight has to cover a distance in space due to its greater orbital velocity as you said. If midnight moves in space then noon also moves in space due to orbital velocity however lower than those of midnights. Covering distance in space means midnight doesn't happen instantly.

Comment: Every point on the outer circle matches with one point on the inner circle There is a one-to-one mapping between points on the circle.  Statements like "midnight has to cover distance in space"  don't make any sense at all.  Midnight is a time, so it doesn't move in space at all.    I still can't imagine why you think there is any problem here but your way of describing is so odd that I think you have just got hold of the wrong end of a stick and run with it (to mix metaphors)

Comment: I think that is the drawing that misleads OP. I guess OP want to say that outer point stay in dark longer, neglecting that light and dark are only dictated by the rotation.

Comment: @ James K, Actually, the opposite is true for me what said.